# Get distinct ids between multiple columns within the same column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a postgresql table that has userids who created a party in one column and an array of userids whom have joined their party.

im wondering if there is any way to return a list of the distinct userids from both the column of their userid and the array, so the distinct list of userids who has either created or joined a party?

Comment: Try querying each distinct list separately, and then UNIONing the two queries.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired outpput

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `union`:

```
select created_userid as userid
from t
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select joined_userid as userid
from t cross join lateral
     unnest(t.joined_userids) joined_userid;
```